# Word for "argument against my current position"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Sorry about the badly phrased title. I'm not quite sure what I'm looking for, either.

My situation is that I'm writing a report arguing for the usage of **A** *over* **B**. I have listed many advantages of **A**, and disadvantages of **B**.

However, I also want to point out that **B** still has its own merits, and cases where it is better than **A**. Is there a word I can use to refer to the section that I argue in favor of **B** in?

The word would kind of mean arguing against my own current position, or arguing against oneself with intent of providing an alternate perspective.

Thanks!

Comment: *Devil's Advocate*? *Antithesis*? *Opposing viewpoint*? *Counterargument*?

Comment: I think counterargument might work? It's not what I have in mind, but it's fairly close. Thanks!

Comment: Pro and con, for and against.

Answer (score 2):

The most simplistic single word is [**counterargument**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/counterargument):

> [Merriam-Webster]
> : an opposing argument
>
> // Joseph Stiglitz's new book, "The Price of Inequality," is the single most comprehensive *counterargument* to both Democratic neoliberalism and Republican laissez-faire theories.
> — Thomas B. Edsall
> // On cost, the *counterargument* is that widespread job losses lead to deep recessions and thus sharp declines in government revenues.
> — *The Economist*, "Bartleby Waging war on recessions," 20 June 2020

Comment: That will work, thank you! Out of curiosity, though, are there less simple words and expressions that have the same meaning?

Comment: @EachOneChew So, in an report, a heading here could simply be *a counterargument*. As I mentioned in a comment under the question, the same heading could instead read something like *playing devil's advocate* or even *a different point of view that shouldn't be entirely discounted*.

Comment: Got it :), thanks